# Azure VM Migration Appliance for Hyper-V

Tags: azure, hyper-v, migrate, windows-server-2016

Creating the topic cause I didn't find any info on this issue, followed strictly the Microsoft documentation below but it didn't work.
I need to migrate a couple of Hyper-V VMs to Azure for a Lab that I want to run some study and tests.

I tried to run the procedure described on the doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/migrate/tutorial-migrate-hyper-v

I proceed with all the steps with no problems, until the migration itself.
On the first time I ran the Azure Site Recovery Configurator, the process went ok with no errors.
It discovered the machines, but I did not start the replication. At that moment I needed to turn off the computer (Windows Server 2016, Hyper-V Host), so I would go back later to start the migration of the VMs.

On another day, when I start the replication of the VMs it got stuck on 1% and not proceeding.
After several hours stuck, I noticed that the VM Host on Infrastructure Servers page was in a "Not Connected" connection status.
According to the initial page of the application (webpage running on port 44368): Discovery agent, Assessment agent and management app are running.
I ran the PowerShell script that would prepare the host to make the migration (Enable Powershell, open WinRM ports, etc).
It's a home lab so I have no firewall and stuff, just a simple router.
On services, every Microsoft service is running except for RecoveryServicesManagementAgent, which stops immediately after I started it.

I tried to register again with Azure Site Recovery Configurator on the Hyper-V Host and I got the following error:
Registration was successful but setup failed to start Microsoft Azure Site Recovery Service on this machine. Please try starting the service manually.
I didn't find any info on this service and error, and it's not on services.MSC console as well. 
I noticed that the server goes to a "Connected" state on Infrastructure Servers page for a while, but it stops again and returns to "Not Connected".

Also, I tried to stop the replication task on the single VM I tried to replicate and it's now stuck on "Disabling Protection" as well, probably because it cant reach the server as there is something wrong with the configuration of services running.

Another problem that I noticed is that my monthly credits are slowly decreasing (Free Trial) after I started this whole process.

Did anyone with a better understanding of this procedure can help me migrate the Hyper-V VMs o Azure or at least point to some direction?

Comment: On a updates status: I created a VM (Nested Virtualization) dedicated to send the synchronization of each VM at a time. This solve the Connection problem, and now my VM Host show as Connected with no issues on Infratructure Servers on Azure Migration Dashboard, so I believe it should be a missconfiguration on previous Virtual Host.

Now, although the sync is show as health and no issues both in Hyper-V host and Azure, it got stuck on 40% progress.

Comment: By following the instructions of this content: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/srinathv/2017/06/28/replication-stuck-replication-not-progressing/, I noticed that there is no network activity on said process cbengine.exe on the appliance server nor any sort of communication between it and Hyper-V Host. The Hyper-V host is on Azure and the machine I trying to replicate got stuck on 40%. On my process server I don't have the cxprocessserver and tmansvc process available (nor the InMage ones, but I guess those are on VMWare).

Answer (score 0):

The query needs a further deeper dive technically.

I recommend you to create a technical support ticket. The ticket enables you to work closely with the support engineers and get a quick resolution to your issue.

Here is the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request to create support case.
please open a Support Ticket so the team can engage directly with you to resolve the issue.